# Showing continuous image in Android

Tags: android, video, bitmap

I want to show about 30 photos in one second,so they will display like a video.

I use Android ImageView in a while(TRUE) loop, but the ImageView not change as I expected.

The ImageView change the picture for about a per second, so wonder if there is another way to

show my photos?

The photos was transferred from a camera using Udp,and I first need to store in a buffer and

than display.

The above part cause a delay in the ImageView.

Part of the code is like this

```
  public void receiveVideoRawData() throws IOException{
        socket_video = new DatagramSocket();
        byte[] buf_rcv = new byte[153600];
        DatagramPacket rawData = new DatagramPacket(buf_rcv, buf_rcv.length);
        Bitmap  image = null;
        socket_video.receive(rawData);//receive a raw data
        image = readMyRawData.readUINT_RGBImage(buf_rcv);//decode the raw data
        ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Bitmap pBitmap = image ;
        pBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 1, blob);
        byte[] bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();
        ardrone_Frame = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata.length);
      }
```

display part

```
  Thread thread=new Thread  (new Runnable() {
     Message message;
    String obj="run";
    int i;
    long start;
    @Override
    public void run() {   
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Log.e("///enter thread ","THREAD");
    while(true){     
        try { 
            Log.e("enter_video_thread","enter_video_thread");
            receiveVideoRawData();
            Log.e("///receiveVideoRawData ","receiveVideoRawData");
            message = handler.obtainMessage(1,obj);
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}

});
public Handler handler = new Handler(){ 
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            String MsgString = (String)msg.obj;
            if (MsgString.equals("run"))
            {         Log.e("///enter handler ","HANDLER");                                           
                          Toast.makeText(ArDroneMain.this,"save image ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/ArdroneVideo.jpg");
                          myImageView.setImageBitmap(ardrone_Frame);    ///Show the image    
                          Toast.makeText(ArDroneMain.this,"show image",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

    }
};
```

Comment: do u want to load the images dynamically? or is it stored in the res?

Comment: The `ImageView` needs to be redrawn after each image has been set. Can you show the code that you are current using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this my making it an animation.
Make images for your animation and keep in a folder in png format.
Animate those images with code below

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true">
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust1" android:duration="200" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust2" android:duration="200" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust3" android:duration="200" />
 </animation-list>
```

then

```
AnimationDrawable rocketAnimation;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  ImageView rocketImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rocket_image);
  rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rocket_thrust);
  rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    rocketAnimation.start();
    return true;
  }
  return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the ffmpeg to create a video of the images and also use the timertask

```
delay=1000/totalImages;

myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {          
            @Override
            public void run() {

                            if(count==imgArr.length)
                              cancel();

                            imageView.setImageResource(imgArr[count]);
                            count++;    

            }

        }, 0, delay);
```

Comment: Getting some error,  Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views